# C++ 17: How to use parameter packs to clarify the order of parameters in a function which all have the same type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm using C++ 17 and want to use template parameters to specify the ordering of the function arguments which all have the same type.
The function has a varying number of arguments and the sorting of these arguments varies too.

I have tried to use the following (simplified) code to which uses parameter packs to implement this.

- The struct `TheInner` is the type used for all function arguments.
- The `Outer` structs are used to specify the order of the passed parameters to the function.

```cpp
// In .h file
struct TheInner {};
 
template<typename T> struct Outer
{
  using Inner = T;
};

struct OuterA : Outer<TheInner> {};
struct OuterB : Outer<TheInner> {};

template<class... Outers> void Method(Outers::Inner... inners);
template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner a, TheInner a2, TheInner b);
template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterB, OuterA>(TheInner a, TheInner b, TheInner a2);

// In .cpp file
template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner a, TheInner a2, TheInner b)
{
  ...
}

template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterB, OuterA>(TheInner a, TheInner b, TheInner a2)
{
  ...
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  Method<OuterA, OuterB, OuterA>(TheInner(), TheInner(), TheInner());
}
```

This currently results in the following error message on GCC:

```
main.cpp:15:32: error: variable or field 'Method' declared void
   15 | template<class... Outers> void Method(Outers::Inner... inners);
      |                                ^~~~~~
main.cpp:15:55: error: expected ')' before 'inners'
   15 | template<class... Outers> void Method(Outers::Inner... inners);
      |                                      ~                ^~~~~~~
      |                                                       )
main.cpp:17:23: error: expected initializer before '<' token
   17 | template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner a, TheInner a2, TheInner b)
      |                       ^
```

Comment: Explicit specializations like `template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner, TheInner, TheInner);` should be declared as close as possible to the primary template declaration. So here if the template `Method` is declared in the header file, all its explicit specializations should also be declared there. This is because if code that hasn't seen the explicit specialization at least declared uses that specialization, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: @aschepler Thank you for the addition. From your answer I conclude that "template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner a, TheInner a2, TheInner b);" and "template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterB, OuterA>(TheInner a, TheInner b, TheInner a2);" should be added directly under "template<class... Outers> void Method(Outers::Inner... inners);" in the header file. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now discovered (after multiple hours) that I was simply missing a `typename` keyword before the `Outers::Inner` type.

A functional code is attached below in the hope that it might help somebody in the future:

```cpp
// Example program
// In .hpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct TheInner {};

template<typename T> struct Outer
{
    using Inner = T;
};

struct OuterA : Outer<TheInner> {};
struct OuterB : Outer<TheInner> {};

template<class... Outers> void Method(typename Outers::Inner... inners);
template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner a, TheInner a2, TheInner b);
template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterB, OuterA>(TheInner a, TheInner b, TheInner a2);

// In .cpp file
// #include <iostream>
// #include <string>

template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner a, TheInner a2, TheInner b)
{
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}

template<> void Method<OuterA, OuterB, OuterA>(TheInner a, TheInner b, TheInner a2)
{
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Method<OuterA, OuterB, OuterA>(TheInner(), TheInner(), TheInner()); // Prints B
    Method<OuterA, OuterA, OuterB>(TheInner(), TheInner(), TheInner()); // Prints A

    // Unimplemented methods:

    // error: too many arguments to function 'void Method(typename Outers::Inner ...) [with Outers = {OuterA, OuterA}]'
    // Method<OuterA, OuterA>(TheInner(), TheInner(), TheInner());

    // undefined reference to `void Method<OuterA, OuterA>(OuterA::Inner, OuterA::Inner)'
    // Method<OuterA, OuterA>(TheInner(), TheInner());
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
B
A
```